# A question based on finding range of a function.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$\mathbf{Question:}$

If $[5\sin(x))] + [\cos(x)] + 6=0$ then what is the range of $f(x)=\sin(x) + \sqrt{3}\cdot \cos(x)$, corresponding to the solution set of the given equation? (Where [.] denotes the greatest integer function).

The answer is $[-2,-\sqrt{3})$. I tried but couldn't get the answer. Can you please explain how to solve this? Thank you for help!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please use Mathjax

Comment: Call $g(x)=\lfloor5\sin x\rfloor+\lfloor\cos x\rfloor+6$. The first thing to figure out is for what $x$ you have $g(x)=0$. Then see what range you get for $f$ with that domain. How far have you got?